# C# Access derived class variables from Base class

Tags: c#

Given the following:

```
public class A
{
  public A()
  {
  
  }

}

public class B : A
{
  public int b;
  
  public B()
  {
    
  }
}

public A a = new B();
print(a.b); // I'd like to have many classes that inherit from A, and storing
// one of them on a single variable. Then access the variables that belong to the //derived class
```

**My goal here is to create several classes that inherit from a base class. Then assign one of the classes to a variable (whose type must be of type "A") and access the variables of the derived class. Is it possible?**

Comment: No, that's now how C# works in general. What **problem** do you think that this will help you to solve?

Comment: My goal here is to create a dictionary that contains variables that derive from class A, then when I pick a random dictionary item, I should be able to access the variables of the derived class. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean "variables that derive from class A"? Are you using "variables" when you mean "instances"?

Comment: Perhaps you want `if (a is B b) print(b.b);` ?

Comment: You're still describing a proposed *solution* to a problem, and it's not going to work. You say you're going to have a dictionary containing various items and you're going to pick one at random. How are *you* or the compiler going to know *what* "variables" you can actually use with that instance?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @mjwills because right now, I have all of these variables inside one class, and whenever I need to access some of them, it gets really confusing determining which ones belong to the class I'm referring to.

A simple example would be: A bunch of "Settings" classes, where each settings class has it's own variables. The way it is now, I see the settings of all "Settings" classes, where i'm only interested in a particular one.

Comment: you should rethink your probolem. When you have a dictionary containing items of your *base*-class, there's no way to access members of a possible derivant. `A` should generally not know **anything** about `B`. In fact that hardly contradicts the [LISKOW-principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: If every one of your derived classes reasonably has a `b`, then `b` should be declared in A, not B. If your parent class is `WheeledVehicle`, then the `NumberOfWheels` should be a property of `WheeledVehicle`, not separate properties in `Car:WheeledVehicle` and `Motorcycle:WheeledVehicle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how inheritance works.

A child can inherit from a parent, but a parent does not inherit from nor have access to anything that is only on the child level.

But you can test to see if it is the subtype, and then explicitly cast, or do the cast while checking.

```
 A one = new B();
 A two = new A();

 //Check if one is of type B
 if (one.GetType() == typeof(B))
 {
        //Now you can explicitly cast it.
        B newVar = (B)one; 
 }

if (two.GetType() == typeof(B))
{
        //False, will not reach this point
}

//Cast and check at same time to new variable called first
if(one is B first)
{
        //Logic here using first
}

if (two is B second)
{
        /False, will not reach this point
}
```

Comment: Would casting to a type given to me by a variable be possible?

For example:
Type someType = typeof(C);
var c = (someType)A ; // obviously doesn't work, but is there a way to make something like it work?